# Unable to send email using Git command through SMTP server of GoDaddy

Tags: git

I am trying to send an email using git command as follows:
$GIT send-email --smtp-pass=**** --smtp-server-port=25 --smtp-debug=1 --no-format-patch --confirm=never --to "$toline" --cc "opensaf-devel@lists.sourceforge.net" "$rr"

The SMTP server is of GoDaddy.

But when I am trying to run the script,I am getting an "authentication required" message even when the email and the password are being provided.

Please help.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Are you missing `--smtp-user` parameter to the command ? https://git-scm.com/docs/git-send-email

Comment: Thanks.I added --smtp-user in the command line and it worked!!!@Chetan Ranpariya